# Control independently apps volume via a physical MIDI controller

Tags: audio, midi

I'm currently working in the audio business, and I got used to always use physical controls to everything.
Does someone know a software to control each app's volume (and solo/mute, if it's possible) via an external MIDI controller (using MIDI CC). All the products that I've seen of this kind are only accessible via GUI, and I would like to have physical control.

Thanks you all!

Comment: I only know a few apps that can even control individual app volumes [Rogue Amoeba mainly]. I don't know one that could also be controlled via midi, unless you could do something like that with Plogue Bidule [which I personally find unfathomable]